# "OR"-constraint with simple-score calculator doesn't work

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to build a simple score-calculator with optaplanner ,but
my "OR"-Constraint doesn't work correctly. Optaplanner says the score is -1, but the score has to be 0. "
Solution should be: "A" only possible at index 2.

Method "no_A_at_Index3" works well. "A_at_Index2_or_Index3" seems to be wrong.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

P.S.  I changed the method from "no_A_at_Index2" to "no_A_at_Index3".

It's strange:

- (!(this.A_at_Index2_or_Index3(nCells)) || !(this.no_A_at_Index2(nCells))) works well.
- (!(this.A_at_Index2_or_Index3(nCells)) || !(this.no_A_at_Index3(nCells))) doesn't work.

  ```
  @Override
  public SimpleScore calculateScore(NCells nCells) {
     int score = 0;
     if (!(this.A_at_Index2_or_Index3(nCells))){
        score--;
     }

     if (!(this.no_A_at_Index3(nCells))){
        score--;
     }
     return SimpleScore.valueOf(score);
  }

  public boolean A_at_Index2_or_Index3(NCells nCells){
      List<Cell> cellList = nCells.getCellList();
      ChomskyRule ruleAtIndex2 = cellList.get(2).getRule();
      ChomskyRule ruleAtIndex3 = cellList.get(3).getRule();   
      int a_counter = 0;
      if ( ruleAtIndex2 != null && ruleAtIndex2.getLeftSide().equals("A")){
              a_counter++;
      }
      if ( ruleAtIndex3 != null && ruleAtIndex3.getLeftSide().equals("A")){
              a_counter++;
      }

      if (a_counter==0 && ruleAtIndex2!=null && ruleAtIndex3!=null){ 
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  public boolean no_A_at_Index3(NCells nCells){ 
     List<Cell> cellList = nCells.getCellList(); 
     ChomskyRule ruleAtIndex3 = cellList.get(3).getRule(); 
     if(ruleAtIndex3!=null && ruleAtIndex3.getLeftSide().equals("A")){return false;} 
     return true; 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this instead:

```
int score = 0;
if (!(this.A_at_Index2_or_Index3(nCells)) || !(this.no_A_at_Index2(nCells)))
   score--;
}
return SimpleScore.valueOf(score);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried it out, but it still doesn't work. method "A_at_Index2_or_Index3" should force A to be at index 2 or index 3. method "no_A_at_Index3" forces A not to be at Index 3. So, A only can be at index 2 ... but it doesn't.